# Jenkins binding when using shared libraries

Tags: jenkins, groovy, shared-libraries

I have a declarative multibranch pipeline in Jenkins that uses shared libraries.  In my shared library I have a global variable say gb1.groovy where I call it from a steps using:

```
gb1(binding)
```

Inside gb1.groovy I do code similar to:

```
Map x = [a: 1, b: 2]
binding.variables.put('x',x)
```

Later on in my pipeline I access variable x and I have access to the Map with all their values.  The problem comes when I call a second global variable say gb2().  Inside gb2.groovy, the binding that was done in gb1 for x is not available (I get an error).  However, the env binding done by Jenkins is available in gb2.

Can any shed some light as why this is happening and what I could do to make x available in gb2 (short of passing the binding and extracting it which is what I am doing today).

Comment: how are you accessing the Map before calling gb2()

Comment: After invoking gb1(binding) I access the map in my pipeline step using x.a for example or if inside a string "${x.a}".   However doing exactly the same thing in gb2 causes an exception that x is not in the binding.

Comment: Its not pass by reference between scripts I dont think. You probably need a return value and then do `binding = gb1(binding)`